# Probabilistic importance value for Caret linear SVM classifier

Tags: r, cross-validation, caret, importance

In a linear SVM model, inside `caret` I would like to get the variable importance after recursive feature elimination, so according to the documentation:

```
library(caret)
library(mlbench)
library(Hmisc)
library(randomForest)
n <- 100
p <- 40
sigma <- 1
set.seed(1)
sim <- mlbench.friedman1(n, sd = sigma)
colnames(sim$x) <- c(paste("real", 1:5, sep = ""),
                         paste("bogus", 1:5, sep = ""))
    bogus <- matrix(rnorm(n * p), nrow = n)
    colnames(bogus) <- paste("bogus", 5+(1:ncol(bogus)), sep = "")
    x <- cbind(sim$x, bogus)
y <- sim$y



normalization <- preProcess(x)
x <- predict(normalization, x)
x <- as.data.frame(x)
subsets <- c(1:5, 10, 15, 20, 25)
set.seed(10)
ctrl <- rfeControl(functions = caretFuncs,
                   method = "repeatedcv",
                   repeats = 5,
                   verbose = FALSE)

lmProfile <- rfe(x, y,
                 sizes = subsets,
                 rfeControl = ctrl)

lmProfile
```

The output of `lmProfile` shows the most 5 important variables, and `predictors(lmProfile)` will show me all the important (retained) predictors after recursive feature elimination. In the [documentation](http://topepo.github.io/caret/featureselection.html) I can read this sentence:

> ... At first this may seem like a disadvantage, but it does provide a more **probabilistic** assessment of predictor importance than a ranking based on a single fixed data set. At the end of the algorithm, a consensus ranking can be used to determine the best predictors to retain.

Could anyone please let me know how I can get these **probabilistic numbers** for each retained variable? In other words I would like to report my important variables not only by showing their ranks, but in a more quantitative way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to look at the results in `lmProfile$variables`. That has the variable importance values per resample and subset size. For your example, using random forest (not linear models), I used `rfFuncs` which is faster since it doesn't tune over `mtry`:

```
set.seed(10)
ctrl <- rfeControl(functions = rfFuncs,
                   method = "repeatedcv",
                   repeats = 5,
                   verbose = FALSE)
set.seed(1)
rfProfile <- rfe(x, y,
                 sizes = subsets,
                 rfeControl = ctrl)
```

The data look like:

```
> head(rfProfile$variables)
                       Overall     var Variables    Resample
selectedVars.real4   18.721549   real4        50 Fold01.Rep1
selectedVars.real2   10.917085   real2        50 Fold01.Rep1
selectedVars.real5   10.305418   real5        50 Fold01.Rep1
selectedVars.real1    8.813745   real1        50 Fold01.Rep1
selectedVars.bogus17  3.932762 bogus17        50 Fold01.Rep1
selectedVars.bogus44  2.384077 bogus44        50 Fold01.Rep1
```

You can get the rate that each predictor was selected at each iteration:

```
library(plyr)
selected <- ddply(rfProfile$variables, 
                      .variables = c("Variables"),
                      function(x) as.data.frame(table(x$var)))
selected$Prob <- selected$Freq/length(rfProfile$control$index)
```

For example:

```
> subset(selected, Variables == 5)
   Variables    Var1 Freq Prob
14         5 bogus14    4 0.08
15         5 bogus17   35 0.70
16         5  bogus2    1 0.02
17         5 bogus26    1 0.02
18         5 bogus44    7 0.14
19         5   real1   50 1.00
20         5   real2   50 1.00
21         5   real3    2 0.04
22         5   real4   50 1.00
23         5   real5   50 1.00
```

These are the variables that were selected when 5 predictors are retained over the 50 resamples. `real1`, `real2`, `real4` and `real5` were all selected each time.

You can also get summary statistics for the `Overall` variable importance score for each predictor also.

Max

Comment: Thank you. Could you also please describe what I should do when I have binary responses? same code with binary `y` will give me only 1 s as the probability